# Google Sheets: How to sum multiple unique criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, sumifs

[image: Table 1]

I'm trying to pull only the "Travel" info from this table and sum the unique values based on multiple criteria. For example I want all Uber expenses grouped by Department and Credit Card and have all the Amounts that are in the same department and Credit Card summed up.

This is what it should look like:

[image: Table 2]

I've been trying to use the `UNIQUE and SUMIF` functions together but I can only figure out how to make it work with 1 criteria.

```
={unique(B2:B10),ArrayFormula(sumif(B2:B10,unique(B2:B10),C2:C10))}
```

[image: Table 3]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try
`=query(A1:E11,"select B,sum(C),D,E where A = 'Travel' group by E,D,B")`

---

[image: Screenshot]